# MVC GroupViewModel with list of SubGroups rendered in checkboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewmodel

I have Domain model with Name and list of `SubGroups`. Basicaly I need to render it in my Edit View with corresponding subGroups checked in boxes and to receive one or more checked `SubGroups`. Bellow is the unfinished code. Thanks for any help.

Domain Model (GroupDomainModel.cs)

```
// Part file, exposed public properties
public virtual string Name
{
  get
  {
    return _Name;
  }
  set
  {
    if (_Name == value)
      return;
    _Name = value;
  }
}

public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<SubGroup> SubGroups
{
  get
  {
    return _SubGroups;
  }
  set
  {
    if (_SubGroups == value)
      return;
    _SubGroups = value;
  }
}
```

View Model (GroupViewModel.cs)

```
public Guid Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public List<SubGroup> SubGroups{get; set;}
public Guid subGroupId {get; set;}

public GroupViewModel() {}
public GroupViewModel(GroupDomainModel g)
{
  Id = g.Id;
  Name = g.Name;
  // missing part, how to add chosen subGroup to SubGroups collection.
}
```

After loading data from the Database, I need to render all subGroups and corresponding `SubGroups` and I need to be able to receive more checked `SubGroups` on the submit.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid Id)
{
  GroupViewModel viewModel = null;
  GroupDomainModel domainModel = GetDomainData(Id);
  viewModel = new GroupViewModel(domainModel);
  return View(viewModel);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(GroupViewModel viewModel)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     GroupDomainModel domainModel = new GroupDomainModel();

     viewModel.SubGroupId // this is Id of the checked subGroup from the view)
  }
}
```